# Interval times on slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a function which iterates through images giving a fade affect. The issue is that the intervals are not looking at the ID set at the bottom and only taking the time for the very last interval set rather than each ID looking at the ID interval, they are all changing at the same time.

I'm not sure if I should be wrapping inside a seperate ID or including it next to the class.

JS

```
function slideSwitch() {

              $(".slideshow").each(function () {
                  var $active = $(this).find(".active");
                  if ($active.length == 0) {
                      $active = $(this).find("IMG:last");
                  }
                  var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $(this).find("IMG:first");

                  $active.addClass('last-active');

                  $next.css({
                      opacity: 0.0
                  })
                      .addClass('active')
                      .animate({
                      opacity: 1.0
                  }, 1000, function () {
                      $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                  });
              });
          }

          $(function () {
              setInterval("slideSwitch('#slide1')", 5000);
              setInterval("slideSwitch('#slide2')", 6000);
              setInterval("slideSwitch('#slide3')", 5000);
          });
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}
.slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}
.slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}
.slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

HTML

```
                         <div class="slideshow" id="slide1">

                          <img src="images/chelsey.png" alt="" class="active"/>
                          <img src="images/rob.png" alt="" />
                          <img src="images/chris.png" alt="" />
                          <img src="images/alex.png" alt="" />

                         </div>


                          <a href="#">

                             <div class="slideshow" id="slide2">

                              <img src="images/ross.png" alt="" class="active"/>
                              <img src="images/miryam.png" alt="" />
                              <img src="images/jo.png" alt="" />
                              <img src="images/katie.png" alt="" />

                             </div>
                            </a>

                </div>
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but you're calling "slideSwitch" and passing arguments to it, but your slideSwitch function doesn't take anyarguments.

Answer (score 1):

First your slideSwitch doesn't take any arguments, then in each slideSwitch call from the interval, you update every slider. Don't you think you should be updating only one slider?

```
function slideSwitch(slider) {    
    var $active = $(slider).find(".active");
    if ($active.length == 0) {
        $active = $(slider).find("IMG:last");
    }
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $(slider).find("IMG:first");

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    })
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}
```

I'd add that you're using setInterval the wrong way. It works but you should either pass a reference to a function like:

```
setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);
```

except in your case you're passing arguments, so you should use an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function(){
    slideSwitch('#slide1');
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhcnvsjL/1/

**EDIT**

Even better since you're using jQuery (why not use full advantages of it?), you could create a plugin that you'd call like `$('#slide1').slider(1000);`

Creating the plugin like that:

```
$.fn.slider = function(interval) {
    var slider = this;

    // rest of the code here
});
```

`fn` being an alias to the `prototype` in javascript, `slider` being the name of the function, and `this` being the element on which the function should have effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/mzxgh18k/1/

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow! I would usually use transitions in CSS to achieve this but it has to be ie8 and ie9 so this sort of jquery animation is new to me. Cheers.

Comment: Well forget about the "plugin" thing then, unless you want to go further with learning of jQuery, but it's a little bit more complex.